# Spring Data MongoDB - projection and search

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I am using "Wildcard text index" in order to search for a pattern in every fields of my class. I am also using projection in order to remove a certain field:

```
@Query(value = "{$text: { $search: ?0 }, fields = "{'notWantedField':0}")
```

However, I would like to prevent from matching something from the unwanted field.

In other words, I would like first to project (and remove fields), then search on the remaining fields.

Is there a way to combine projection and search while keeping the wildcard search?

Thanks a lot.

I am using spring-data-mongodb 1.10.8

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be a **$and** operator combined with a **$regex**.

For example following the Mongodb documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text, if you suppose to create a *text* index combining *subject* and *author* (`db.articles.createIndex({"author": "text", "subject": "text"})`, you can exclude *author* field with this query:

```
db.articles.find( {$and: [{ $text: { $search: "coffee" } }, {"author": {'$regex' : '^((?!coffe).)*$', '$options' : 'i'}}]}, {"author": 0})
```

In your case, considering that your index is a wildcard, you must exclude, using the *regex*, all the fields that are also in the projection.

Comment: Thank you. From what I understand, you prevent a match in the excluded field but if it matches another field, we want to consider it as a positive response. Meaning if the string coffee appears in both author and subject fields, it should not be filtered out.